# Prove by minimum counterexample that $2^n>10n$ for $n>5$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, examples-counterexamples

> Prove by minimum counterexample that for all integers $n>5$ the statement $2^n>10n$ is true.

**Attempt**: Let $S$ be a set of counterexamples, $S=\{n \in \mathbb{Z_+}: 2^n \le 10n, \space n>5 \}$. Let $m \in S$ be the smallest element of $S$, so $m>5$. Then, $m-1 \notin S$. So, we have $$2^{m-1}>10(m-1) \\ 2^m>20(m-1)$$

I am stuck here. I dont know how to get rid of that $-1$. Help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is sufficient to show $20(m-1)>10m\iff  m>2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt has some flaws.
The method should show that there is no minimal counterexample by using the fact that eavery nonempty subset of $\mathbb Z_+$ has a minimal element.
But you cannot show that $S$ is empty, simply because $S$ isn't empty (in fact $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. So by actually taking the miniumal element of this $S$, you take $m=1$. Then indeed $m-1=0\notin S$, but so what?
Adjust the definition of $S$ so that its emptyness is precisely the statement that there are no counterexamples to "$2^n>10n$ and $n>5$".

Comment: oh right. Thanks for pointing it out. I think saying that $S=\{n \in \mathbb{Z_+} : 2^n >10n, \space n>5\}$ suffices.